add dynamic property per object , slow GC
I need to add dynamic properties to each object. When I create a large number of objects, my JVM memory usage increases significantly, resulting in frequent full GCs. Here is my test code:
class Test {
    static class A {
        A() {
            def mc = new ExpandoMetaClass(A, false, true)
            mc.setProperty("name", UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            mc.initialize()
            this.metaClass = mc
        }
    }

    static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            A a = new A()
            String name = a.name
            if (i == 99990) {
                println "debug"
            }
        }
    }
}

I add metaClass to each A object, and each metaClass has a different property. When I run this code and use jmap -histo:live 98450 | head -20 to analyze the memory usage, I notice a significant increase in memory consumption.
 num     #instances         #bytes  class name (module)
-------------------------------------------------------
   1:      12899564      722375584  org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaMethodIndex$Entry
   2:      10500076      420003040  java.util.LinkedHashMap$Entry (java.base@11.0.21)
   3:       9003475      242629352  [Ljava.lang.Object; (java.base@11.0.21)
   4:       8999480      215987520  org.codehaus.groovy.util.FastArray
   5:        900714      123283440  [Ljava.util.HashMap$Node; (java.base@11.0.21)
   6:         99995      103997360  [Lorg.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaMethodIndex$Entry;
   7:       1200034       67201904  java.util.LinkedHashMap (java.base@11.0.21)
   8:       1599946       51198272  groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty
   9:        500094       32006016  java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap (java.base@11.0.21)
  10:        200101       28869264  [Ljava.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node; (java.base@11.0.21)


Upon investigation, I found that the metaProperty of each object is stored in org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ThreadManagedMetaBeanProperty#instance2Prop, where the key is the original object. Using soft references to manage memory, I observed that when there are a large number of short-lived objects, soft references are not released in a timely manner, causing extensive GC activity and longer GC times.
This might not be the correct usage of ExpandoMetaClass. Could you suggest the best practices for using ExpandoMetaClass to avoid such memory issues?
